# How to prove that for any $k$ between $2$ and $n-2$ we have $\binom{n}{k} \ \ge \binom{n}2$

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to show that for any $k$ from $2$ to $n-2$ we have $\binom{n}{k} \ \ge \binom{n}2$.

**What I tried**

I started from the fact that $\binom{n}{k} \le \binom{n}{k+1}$ if $k \le \frac{n-1}{2}$ and by using the symmetry of binomial coefficients we also have this for $k \ge\frac{n+1}{2}$, but I don't know how to proceed from here on out and tie this to $k$ being between $2$ and $n-2$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please edit your question?

Comment: So sorry , wrote it first on latex and forgot to add the $, is it better now ? @LionHeart

Comment: Welcome to MSE! When writing LaTeX, dollar signs activate math mode, which should *only* be used for mathematical expressions. Plain text / prose should be outside of math mode. On this site, you can also use Markdown formatting for plain text. Please take a look at how I have edited your post to see how to format future questions (and mathematics more generally).

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thank you so much , this is my first time asking so i was confused , decided to write it down on latex first then paste here , now i get it. Appreciate the help and edit so much .

Comment: For $k=2$ the inequality is obviously false. You may want to use non-strict inequality in the result ( $\binom{n}{k} \ge \binom{n}{2}$ ) or strict inequality in the hypothesis ( "for any $k$ strictly between $2$ and $n-2$")

Comment: @jjagmath yess  i am trying to show the  non-strict inequality

Comment: Have you considered induction and something like $${n+1\choose k}={n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1} > {n\choose 2}+{n\choose 1}={n+1\choose 2}$$

Comment: Then edit your question. Type `\ge` to get $\ge$

Comment: @jjagmath done , thank you

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, choosing 2 objects out of $n$ and choosing $n-2$ objects out of $n$ are the same thing; you're really just sorting them into two groups, so you can interpret $\binom n 2$ or $\binom n {n-2}$ as being the number of distinct ways to form the smaller group. If $n < k < n-2$ then the smaller group (the lesser of $k$ and $n-k$) will be at least 3, thus there are more ways to form it.

Perhaps more explicitly, if $2<k<n-2$ then $(n-k)! < (n-2)!$
$$\binom n k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
$$\binom n 2 = \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}$$
$$\frac{\binom n k}{\binom n 2} = \frac{2!(n-2)!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{2 \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-3) \dots 2 \cdot 1}{k \cdot (k-1) \dots 2 \cdot 1 \cdot (n-k) \dots 2 \cdot1}$$
$$= \frac{(n-2)\cdot(n-3)\dots(n-k+1)}{k\cdot(k-1)\dots4\cdot3} \geq 1$$

Comment: "Mathematically"? The first combinatorial argument is also a valid *mathematical* argument.

Comment: Yes that is a good point I have updated my phrasing

Comment: thank you so much ,i tried this approach too , however for the last line and majoration of 1 , i don't get how we can show that it works as n-k+1 might be only greater than 1 , i'm wondering if there is any other more rigorous method

Comment: I would interpret "n-k+1 is only greater than 1" to mean that n-k+1=2, since the only integer it's greater than is 1. Then we'd have n-k=1, and so k=n-1>n-2 which is contrary to the hypothesis. n-k+1 is guaranteed to be at least 4 if k<n-2

Comment: @DanishChef i see it now , thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Proof by induction:

(1) Base case: $n=6$, easy to verify, $2<k=3<6-2$,
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~\binom{6}{3}>\binom{6}{2},~~\text{True.}$$

(2) Assume it is true for $n=m$, where $m>6$ and $m\in \mathbb{N^+}$, so we have:

$$\binom{m}{k}>\binom{m}{2}$$

(3) Induction step: when $n=m+1$,

$$\begin{align}
\binom{m+1}{k}&=\frac{(m+1)!}{k!(m+1-k)!}=\frac{m+1}{m+1-k}\binom{m}{k}>\frac{m+1}{m+1-k}\binom{m}{2}\\
\\
&=\frac{m+1}{m+1-k}\cdot\frac{m!}{2!(m-2)!}=\frac{m-1}{m+1-k}\cdot\frac{(m+1)!}{2!(m-1)!}=\frac{m-1}{m+1-k}\binom{m+1}{2}
\end{align}$$

since $k>2,~~\rightarrow~~m-1>m+1-k$, therefore:

$$\frac{m-1}{m+1-k}\binom{m+1}{2}>\binom{m+1}{2}$$

So we have:

$$\binom{m+1}{k}>\binom{m+1}{2}$$

Proof is completed.

Comment: Thank you so much , may i ask why did we start with n=6 as our base case?

Comment: If $n<6$, then there is no integer between $2$ and $n-2$ ("between" means strictly $"<"$ or $">"$). For example, $n=5$, no integer $k$ such as $2<k<3$ @emanon111

Comment: thank you so much i see it now !

Comment: You are welcome, if you like it, please vote and accept $\checkmark$ my answer :) @emanon111